# Instagram - pull LESS than 20 media + pagination

Tags: pagination, limit, instagram, media, instagram-api

I've found out, that you can get latest public posts of an instagram page by using simple media url:

https://www.instagram.com/PAGE_ID_NAME/media/

I've noticed that it returnes JSON with maximum of 20 posts and information if there are "`more_available`".

Now I don't want to pull 20 posts - I just need like 5 and provide a pagination for possible more - but I did not find how to limit these results - I've tried adding `?limit=NUMBER` and `?count=NUMBER` without success.

So 2 questions arise:

1. How do I limit results *while using url structure above*?
2. How do I make pagination links *while using url structure above*?

**Is 1. & 2. even possible?**

Answer (score 0):

Try building this url. 

[https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token={YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN}&COUNT={NUMBER-RESULTS}](https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/%7Btag-name%7D/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN)

Get a list of recently tagged media. Use the max_tag_id and min_tag_id parameters in the pagination response to paginate through these objects.
PARAMETERS

**COUNT**   Count of tagged media to return.
**MIN_TAG_ID**  Return media before this min_tag_id.
**MAX_TAG_ID**  Return media after this max_tag_id.

Comment: I know I can get the info using access token, I wanted to avoid that ... :) Therefore I've emphasized *while using url structure above* ..., but thanks, this will be helpful to others :-)